# RandomPoint fails with a large enough number of points

Tags: bugs, random, regions

**Bug introduced in 10.2.0 and fixed in 10.3.1.**

 `RandomPoint` is new in 10.2.0.

---

I have defined a simple ellipsoidal parametric region:

```
With[{a = 10, b = 7, c = 1.5},
  ℛ = ParametricRegion[{a Cos[u] Cos[v], b Cos[u] Sin[v], c Sin[u]},
  {{u, -π/2, π/2}, {v, -π, π}}]
];
```

I would then like to generate some (thousands) of random points inside this region.
However, `RandomPoint[ℛ, n]` fails if `n` is 152 or larger (determined with trial & error).

```
pts = RandomPoint[ℛ, 152];
```

> ```
> Function::flpar: Parameter specification {Statistics`RandomNumberGenerationDump`x$138799[1],
>     Statistics`RandomNumberGenerationDump`x$138799[2]}
>   in Function[{Statistics`RandomNumberGenerationDump`x$138799[1],
>     Statistics`RandomNumberGenerationDump`x$138799[2]},2.1298 (1-<<46>>[1])^2
>       Statistics`RandomNumberGenerationDump`x$138799[1] (1-
>         Statistics`RandomNumberGenerationDump`x$138799[2])^3+<<11>>+1.91753 <<1>>^3 <<
>       1>>^3] should be a symbol or a list of symbols. >>
> ```

Is this a bug? I'm using Mathematica 10.3.0 on Xubuntu Linux 15.10.

**Update**:
The behavior is random seed-dependent. For example, with `SeedRandom[4]`, I get no errors. With 1, 2, 3 or 5, I do.

With the code

```
Monitor[Do[Check[RandomPoint[ℛ, n], Print[n]], {n, 5, 200}], n]
```

the smallest `n` which fails is so far 14.

**Update 2**:
After some more testing, I believe it can fail with any `n`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem with 10.3.1 on Mac.  Why don't you upgrade to 10.3.1 and see if that fixes it?  I think 10.3.1 is free for people with a 10.3.0 license.  It's a bugfix release, so there's no good reason not to try it.

Comment: Is this reproducible with the number 152?  I'm using the same version, and if I try with 100 it will sometimes work, sometimes not

Comment: @JasonB I tried this and couldn't reproduce it: `Monitor[
 Do[Check[RandomPoint[\[ScriptCapitalR], k], Print[k]], {k, 5, 200, 
   3}],
 k
 ]`  I think that we'll need to use `SeedRandom` to get a consistently reproducible example.

Comment: @JasonB see update, it appears it is random seed-dependent.

Comment: [I cannot reproduce it with `SeedRandom[1]` on Linux.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2fh188f39vdlmwg/Screenshot%202016-02-04%2013.16.53.png?dl=0)  The only difference remaining between our systems seems to be that you have 10.3.0 and I have 10.3.1.  Time for an upgrade?

Comment: I can confirm this goes away if you upgrade to 10.3.1 from 10.3.0

Comment: @Szabolcs worth a [tag:bugs] tag?

Comment: @shrx Added.  Also reproduced in 10.2 Mac.  There's no RandomPoint in 10.1 so the bug can't be present there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bug appears to be fixed in the latest version of Mathematica (10.3.1), as confirmed by [@JasonB](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/9490/jason-b) and [@Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/12/szabolcs).