# RandomPoint works with a 2D ImplicitRegion but fails for any higher dimension

Tags: random, regions

This is inspired by [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/105736/9490) which features code that I cannot get to work at all, and I tried to figure out why.

It boils down to using the function `RandomPoint`, which is new and a little bit tricky to use (see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/97430/9490) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/105649/9490)), in combination with `ImplicitRegion`.

Here are two and three dimensional regions,

```
twoDRegion = 
  ImplicitRegion[{0 <= a <= 1, 0 <= b <= 1, a + b == 1}, {a, b}];
threeDRegion = 
  ImplicitRegion[{0 <= a <= 1, 0 <= b <= 1, 0 <= c <= 1, 
    a + b + c == 1}, {a, b, c}];
```

These regions are the set of all positive tuples that sum to 1,

[`RandomPoint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomPoint.html) works on the 2D version, but not the 3D version,

```
RandomPoint /@ {twoDRegion, threeDRegion}
(* {{0.146978, 0.853022}, 
 RandomPoint[
  ImplicitRegion[
   0 <= a <= 1 && 0 <= b <= 1 && 0 <= c <= 1 && a + b + c == 1, {a, b,
     c}]]} *)
```

Interestingly, `RegionPlot` also has trouble with the 3D version,

```
RegionPlot /@ {twoDRegion, threeDRegion}
```

[image]

but `DiscretizeRegion` can handle both

```
DiscretizeRegion /@ {twoDRegion, threeDRegion}
```

[image]

This led me to think that I just need to discretize before selecting the random point, and this in fact works for the 3D case

```
RandomPoint@DiscretizeRegion@# & /@ {twoDRegion, threeDRegion}
(* {{0.579605, 0.420395}, {0.154819, 0.0404491, 0.804732}} *)
```

But it won't work for higher dimensions since `DiscretizeRegion` is limited to 3 dimensions or lower.

Is this a bug?

Comment: I have run into the problem you describe here myself and have accepted the behavior as either an incomplete implementation or a design choice by the developers, not a bug. That is only a speculation on my part, of course. I hope you get an informed answer, perhaps from someone connected to WRI.

Comment: Dear OP, did you find any solution for this issue? I also have similar requirement to use RandomPoint in higher dimension region. Thanks

Comment: Any word on a fix for this?  I can't sample from `BooleanRegion`s of with `n>3`.

Answer (score 3):

In 12.1.1 this is still a problem. For a workaround I've noticed that making the `a + b + c == 1` plane 'thicker' using `1 - 10^-6 <= a + b + c <= 1` allows you to generate points, and you can correct the small error by using `#/Total[#] &` so that `a + b + c` is exactly 1 without introducing any significant bias into the sampling:

```
#/Total[#] &@
 RandomPoint@
  ImplicitRegion[{0 <= a <= 1, 0 <= b <= 1, 0 <= c <= 1, 
    1 - 10^-6 < a + b + c <= 1}, {a, b, c}]
```

Interestingly, the thinner the final inequality gets the harder *Mathematica* has to work, and when close to the `$MachineEpsilon` it hangs indefinitely on my machine. There is definitely something *Mathematica* doesn't like about sampling in 3D with a strict equality constraint.